# spring boot aop won't work in class annotated as @Component and only works in @Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have no idea why my spring boot aop pointCut expression won't work into other classes annotated @Component, it seems to be working only in @Controller.

approaches I have tried:

1, separate the classes in distinct files;

2, change to AutoAnnotationConfig with @Bean;

3, ...

but none worked

what I expect:

I presume that the aop point could cut into methods in @Component annotated classes;

Here is the code, and please refer to the comment line underneath.

```
package com.example.demo.basic;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class B19_aop {

    @RequestMapping("/basic/aop")
    public String main(Map<String, String> map) {

        map.put("print", "test");

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ReaderAutoAnnotationConfig.class);
        Reader reader = ctx.getBean(Reader.class);
        System.out.println(reader.read());

        return "common";
    }
}


interface Book{
    public String getData();
}

@Component
class Magazine implements Book{
    private String data;
    Magazine(){ }
    public String getData(){
        return "reading magazine";
    }
}

@Component
class Reader {
    private Book book;

    @Autowired
    Reader(Book book){
        this.book = book;
    }

    public String read(){
        return this.book.getData();
    }
};

@Aspect
@Component
class AOP{

    // **************************************************
    // @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.example.demo.basic.Magazine.*(..))")
    // **************************************************
    // works not, why ?

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.example.demo.basic.B19_aop.*(..))")
    // works nice !
    public void myPointCut(){ }

    @Around("myPointCut()")
    public Object myAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        String className = pjp.getClass().toString();
        String method = pjp.getSignature().getName();
        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
        Object result = pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("point cut advice works!");
        return result;
    }

}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo.basic")
class ReaderAutoAnnotationConfig{}
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you creating a new `ApplicationContext` instance from the controller class ? Is your `Aspect` in the scan path for `ReaderAutoAnnotationConfig` ? The reason your `Magazine` or `Reader` instances are not adviced is because , the `AOP` and the target classes are not part of the same Spring application context.

Comment: thx, "the AOP and the target classes are not part of the same Spring application context. " sounds quite reasonable, but, how can I tell the ApplicationContext instance to include the AOP Aspect ?

Comment: question: `Why are you creating a new ApplicationContext instance from the controller class ?` I am trying to do some demos via spring mvc; question: `Is your Aspect in the scan path for ReaderAutoAnnotationConfig ? `, I think yes, class AOP is defined in the same package.

Comment: The  `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.xxxx")` should also include the `AOP` in its scan path. But again , you already have an Spring MVC project which contains the `@Controller` , why do you need another `ApplicationContext` ?

Comment: That case instead of creating a new application context , what happens if you `@Autowired Reader`  within `B19_aop` and call the `reader.read()` from `main()`

Comment: Yes!!! thx a lot. but, what if I do want to create a new instance and include the AOP in it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233595/discussion-between-feiyuerenhai-and-r-g).